# Finger detection doesn't work well

Tags: ros, kinect, hand-interaction, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I followed the instruction on finger detection [HERE](http://www.ros.org/wiki/mit-ros-pkg/KinectDemos/FingerDetection). For my experiment, the skeleton tracking and hand detection did work well, but I had problems on finger detection.

According to this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haCyDo7y3BE. The result suppose to be like in the vdo, but not for me. [HERE is my result http://upic.me/i/ig/finger_detection.png](http://upic.me/i/ig/finger_detection.png)

I have already looked through the code and found that on ~/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/hand_interaction/src/analyze_hands.cpp which is my clusters is always 0.

Here is a piece of my console.

```
dist:  0.710981  palm: 124  digits: 0 219.509 
got hand 0.06, -0.116754, 0.684308 open
dist:  0.701354  palm: 115  digits: 5 224.323
clusters: 0
got hand 0.06, -0.115469, 0.660131 open
dist:  0.684888  palm: 120  digits: 5 232.556 
clusters: 0
got hand 0.06, -0.117159, 0.642459 open
dist:  0.671496  palm: 128  digits: 48 239.252 
clusters: 0
got hand 0.06, -0.117360, 0.636094 open
dist:  0.648688  palm: 118  digits: 0 250.656
got hand 0.06, -0.119665, 0.617218 open
```

I stuck on what's wrong with my configuration?
Can anyone point me out of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Mintra.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12581/finger-detection-doesn%27t-work-well./) by [Mintra](https://answers.ros.org/users/1573/mintra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have already post it to Kinect+ROS mailing list.

se7oluti0n, who answered my question and it did work for me.
Let me copy this msg for you all.

I have had the same problem before but I have solved it by edit some value in this piece of code : in function void radiusFilter(int nnthresh, double tol) of analyze_hands.cpp:

```
for(uint i=0;i<full.points.size();++i){
    if(inds2[i]==0) continue;
      sc2.NNN(full.points[i],searchinds,tol);
      //TO   DO: this is good for face-on, but not great for tilted hands
     if(searchinds.size()>(530-500*distfromsensor)){
         inds.push_back(i);
       if(searchinds.size()>(570-500*distfromsensor))
            label=0;
         else
            label=1;
         for(uint j=0;j<searchinds.size();++j)
            inds2[searchinds[j]]=label;
      }
```

}

this functions will separate palm and digits by look at each point of the hand point cloud, If number of points around that point ( within radius tol ( 2nd parameters )) is bigger than (530-500*distfromsensor), this point will belong to palm and vice versa.

replace 530 and 570 with your value ( may be the size of the cluster depends on people ) or edit radius tol
my case is 830 and 870 and it worked.

Hope that helps..

---

Originally posted by [Mintra](https://answers.ros.org/users/1573/mintra/) with karma: 46 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3